# Total number of distinct Texas Hold' em poker games

Tags: combinatorics, gambling

In a variation of poker called [Texas Hold' em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_hold_%27em) players, each player receives two cards; the dealer also deals a total of five community cards in three phases: in the first phase the dealer deals the first three cards, in the remaining two phases the dealer deals one card. Many games will end before all five cards have been dealt, but regardless I'd like to calculate the total number of Texas Hold' em games that are played all the way to the end.

There are at least two and at most ten players, and the game is played with a standard deck of $52$ cards. If there are $p$ players, this means the total number of cards drawn from the deck by the end of a game is $2 \cdot p + 5$, which means the upper bound for the total number of possible poker games is $52 \choose{2 \cdot p + 5}$. For just two players, this yields around $3.679 \times 10^9$ games, while for ten players this number increases to a whopping $4.7755 \times 10^{14}$ games.

However, this is an overestimate, because the order of each pair of player cards does not matter. Neither does the order of the three cards in the first phase. So taking into account this duplication, I figured I should divide the total like this:

$$
\begin{align}
T &= {52 \choose{2 \cdot p + 5}} \Leftrightarrow \\
T' &= \frac{T}{\left(2! \right)^p \cdot3!}
\end{align}
$$

But [for some $p$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kxfxyobjr0) the division by $3!$ yields a non-integer number of games, which isn't possible. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $T = {52 \choose{2 \cdot p + 5}}$ is incorrect (too small as it ignores order) and should be $T = \frac{52!}{(52- 2 \cdot p - 5)!}$

This is divisible by $(2!)^p \cdot 3!$ to give an integer

Comment: So you mean that if I use *choose*, I'm actually grouping together distinct games as if they are the same because they contain the same cards in a different order?

Comment: Different from the original question, if I wanted to know all possible hold' em games from the perspective of e.g. the first player, could I then use *choose* to group together games where the other players happen to have the same cards in different orders?

Comment: If you use ${52 \choose{2 \cdot p + 5}}$ then these are the cards dealt, but ignores the order and so where they go.

Comment: Yo could divide the number by $(p-1)!$ for the "first player perspective" if  they do not care which of the others might have the Ace and King of Hearts, beyond the point that somebody else might.  But my understanding is that in reality they do care, as playing order does affect sophisticated  bet/check/fold strategies.

Comment: I'm gonna have to have another think then, I wanted to calculate something like a [blackjack basic strategy chart](https://wizardofodds.com/games/blackjack/strategy/calculator/) for poker, given the starting cards. Thanks for your answer and replies.